# Find the range of $p\in\mathbb{R}$ such that it is a $C^n$ class function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$n\in\mathbb{N}$

Find the range of $p\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{ \,
    \begin{aligned}
    & |x|^p \sin{\frac{1}{x}} &(x\neq0)\\
    & 0 &(x=0)
    \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
is a $C^n$-class function on $\mathbb{R}$.


I'm stuck on the following idea.

$ⅰ) x\geq0$

Let $g(x)=x^p,h(x)=\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$. Since $g$ and $h$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, we can say $gh$ can be differentiated infinitely many times on $\mathbb{R}$ from Leibniz's theorem.


$ⅱ) x<0$

...I don't know how to discuss it here.
I'm also stuck because I don't know what equation/relation has to do with the range of p.

Thanks for your any help.

Comment: Please be a little more careful. When you say $h$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ in i), that statement is not true because $h$ is not defined at $0$ (and cannot be defined continuously as well). What you need to do is go back straight to the definitions.  First, think about just continuity : when is the function $f$ continuous at zero? For this, you need $\lim_{x \to 0} |x|^p \sin \frac 1x = 0$ : so when does this occur? Next, think about just differentiability : when is $|x|^p \sin \frac 1x$ just differentiable at zero? We need to generalize this for this problem now.

Comment: $f(-x) = -f(x)$, so $f$ is just as well behaved when $x < 0$ as it is when $x > 0$. It is only when $x = 0$ that trouble arises.

Comment: Thank you.
I'll think about it some more.